# Sizing image using % in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying so size the banner image with CSS using the % so that it can scale as I resize it.
But soon as i set the height of the page as a % then the whole thing disappears.

```
.banner{
    background-image:url(img/banner.PNG);
    background-color: rgb(0, 121, 255);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height: 10%;
    width: 100%;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

So currently it is not not displaying anything because at the moment.
How do i get it to display the image ant that it remains 10% of the screen size

Comment: is banner a block element ? does it's parent have height set ?

Comment: you could use the padding top / bottom trick (but this maintains the aspect ratio of the div rather than having it 10% height of the screen): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.banner{
background-image:url(img/banner.PNG);
background-color: rgb(0, 121, 255);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height: 10vh;
width: 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
}
```

give height of banner equal to 10vh, it will always take the 10% of your screen size.